# Simple WordPress word/phrase Auto hyperlink plugin not linking

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, automation, hyperlink

I am writing a WordPress plugin that automatically creates hyperlinks to corresponding posts based on the settings configured in the plugin's options page. The plugin creates hyperlinks for specific post types, and the number of hyperlinks per phrase per post can be set by the user in the settings page. However, i cant figure out why its not working. i cant see what i am missing

```
<?PHP
/*
Plugin Name: Auto Hyperlink
Plugin URI: https://example.com/
Description: Automatically creates hyperlinks to corresponding posts.
Version: 3.3
Author: Tamara Oweibo
Author URI: https://example.com/
*/

// Add the plugin settings page
function auto_hyperlink_settings_page() {
  add_options_page(
    'Auto Hyperlink Settings',
    'Auto Hyperlink',
    'manage_options',
    'auto-hyperlink-settings',
    'auto_hyperlink_settings_page_content'
  );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'auto_hyperlink_settings_page' );


//defining HOUR_IN_SECONDS constant
define( 'HOUR_IN_SECONDS', 60 * 60 );

// Define the plugin settings fields
function auto_hyperlink_settings_init() {
  register_setting( 'auto_hyperlink_settings_group', 'auto_hyperlink_max_links', array(
    'type' => 'integer',
    'default' => 2, // set the default value to 2
    'sanitize_callback' => 'intval'
  ));

  add_settings_section(
    'auto_hyperlink_settings_section',
    'Auto Hyperlink Settings',
    '',
    'auto-hyperlink-settings'
  );

  // Add hyperlinks max fields
  add_settings_field(
    'auto_hyperlink_max_links',
    'Maximum Number of Links',
    'auto_hyperlink_max_links_input',
    'auto-hyperlink-settings',
    'auto_hyperlink_settings_section'
  );

  register_setting( 'auto_hyperlink_settings_group', 'auto_hyperlink_post_types', array(
    'type' => 'array',
    'default' => array( 'post', 'page', 'terms' ),
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
  ));

  //Add Post Type Options Select fields
  add_settings_field(
    'auto_hyperlink_post_types',
    'Post Types to Apply',
    'auto_hyperlink_post_types_input',
    'auto-hyperlink-settings',
    'auto_hyperlink_settings_section'
  );
  
  // Add nonce verification
  add_action( 'admin_post_update_auto_hyperlink_settings', 'auto_hyperlink_settings_verify_nonce' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'auto_hyperlink_settings_init' );

// Verify the nonce
function auto_hyperlink_settings_verify_nonce() {
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['auto_hyperlink_settings_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['auto_hyperlink_settings_nonce'], 'auto_hyperlink_settings_nonce' ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Security check failed.' );
  }
}


// Render the maximum number of links input field
function auto_hyperlink_max_links_input() {
  $value = get_option( 'auto_hyperlink_max_links', 2 );
  echo "<input type='number' name='auto_hyperlink_max_links' value='{$value}' min='1' max='10' />";
}

// Render the plugin settings page content
function auto_hyperlink_settings_page_content() {
  // Generate a nonce
  $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'auto_hyperlink_settings_nonce' );
  ?>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>">
      <?php
        // Add the nonce field
        printf( '<input type="hidden" name="auto_hyperlink_settings_nonce" value="%s">', esc_attr( $nonce ) );
        // Add the action field
        printf( '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_auto_hyperlink_settings">' );
        settings_fields( 'auto_hyperlink_settings_group' );
        do_settings_sections( 'auto-hyperlink-settings' );
        submit_button();
      ?>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}


// Render input fields for selecting Post types
function auto_hyperlink_post_types_input() {
  $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );
  $selected_post_types = get_option( 'auto_hyperlink_post_types', array( 'post', 'page', 'terms' ) );

  foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    $checked = in_array( $post_type->name, $selected_post_types ) ? 'checked' : '';
    printf( '<label><input type="checkbox" name="auto_hyperlink_post_types[]" value="%s" %s> %s</label><br>',
      esc_attr( $post_type->name ),
      $checked,
      esc_html( $post_type->labels->name )
    );
  }
}


// Add the hyperlinks to the content on single post pages
function auto_hyperlink( $content ) {
  global $wpdb;

  // Fetch the cached max_links value
  $max_links = get_transient( 'auto_hyperlink_max_links' );

  // If the cached value is not found, get the option value and cache it for 24 hours
  if ( false === $max_links ) {
    $max_links = get_option( 'auto_hyperlink_max_links', 2 );
    set_transient( 'auto_hyperlink_max_links', $max_links, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
  }

  // Fetch the selected post types from the options table
  $selected_post_types = get_option( 'auto_hyperlink_post_types', array( 'post', 'page', 'terms' ) );

  // Prepare the post types array for use in the SQL query
  $post_types = array_map( 'esc_sql', $selected_post_types );
  $post_types_string = "'" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "'";

  // Fetch the post IDs
  $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
    $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ($post_types_string)"
    )
  );

  foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_title_encoded = wp_kses_post( $post_title );
    $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $link_text = "<a href='{$permalink}'>{$post_title_encoded}</a>";

    // Check if the post title is already linked
    $pos = strpos( $content, $link_text );
    if ( false !== $pos ) {
      continue;
    }

    // Create the link
    $linked_content = str_ireplace( $post_title, $link_text, $content );

    // Check if we have reached the maximum number of links
    if ( substr_count( $linked_content, $link_text ) >= $max_links ) {
      break;
    }

    // Update the content
    $content = $linked_content;
  }

  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'auto_hyperlink' );
?>
```